# How to create a local calendar on Ubuntu Phone

Tags: ubuntu-touch, calendar

How can I create a second local calendar on Ubuntu Phone? If I try to do it with the button in the calendar app, it just leads me to the account settings but there is no option to create another local calendar.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to create a second calendar is via the commandline on the Ubuntu Phone:
`syncevolution --create-database backend=evolution-calendar database=Hollidays`
*'Hollidays' is the name of the new calendar*

Answer (score 0):

You can download the calendar app made by the guys from “ubuntu core app developpers”, it synces with the events scope and it has also the possibility to sync whit other account's calendars. It's useful even if it had some bugs (mostly when syncing whit other accounts like onenote or google) last time I checked.

Comment: The problem is that when you trying to add a new calendar it sends you to the account settings. And there is no option to create a new local account. So the above seems to be the only way to achieve that.