# Syncing Calendar and Contacts with Ubuntu Phone

Tags: sync, evolution, phone, calendar, contacts

one topic that I find is completely neglected on the web is the question of syncing your Ubuntu Phone contacts and calendar with Ubuntu (i.e. Evolution).

With a full Ubuntu on the phone I would expect this to be a fundamental, out-of-the-box functionality.

Is it?
If yes, how does it work?
How were your experiences?

And a jolly happy New Year to y'all.
Armin

Comment: Please search before posting a new question. These has been answered here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/360466/ . It is the alternate way which uses syncevolution. By default Ubuntu touch also uses syncevolution script for syncing contacts. If it doesn't work, then file a bug on launchpad.

Comment: @KhurshidAlam, thanks for the pointer regarding contacts. However, this doesn't seem to answer the part about syncing calendars. So far I haven't seen a method that does this without developer mode, is there any?

Comment: @StephanHerrmann Calendar sync is not very different than contacts. You select evolution calendar name and use `backend=evolution-calandar`. For more info refer here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/616081/ubuntu-touch-add-contact-list-and-calendars and https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SyncEvolution/synchronize-multiple-google-calendars-with-evolution-calendars