# Ubuntu Touch -Calander app auto sync

Tags: ubuntu-touch

Is there a setting that I can turn on to auto update all my calanders on my Ubuntu devices, when I make an update to an event on one? Today, I added a new event on my Touch phone. When I got home I looked at my calander app on my Ubuntu tablet and the event had not auto synced to it. So I had to manually sync my tablet calander app. I have had a look and cannot find a setting to turn on to auto sync.

Comment: What level of automation are you asking about? Do you have basic syncing a la [syncing-calendar-and-contacts-with-ubuntu-phone](http://askubuntu.com/questions/715963/syncing-calendar-and-contacts-with-ubuntu-phone) running?

Comment: All I want is out of the box functionality so that when I give my Google calendar and contact login details, that any changes made to these two will be synced automatically to my Touch device. No I have not got this running as I was not aware that it worked this way. I tried to install SyncEvolution to my phone and I cannot download it. However, downloading my contacts in a vcf file seems a static option to me not dynamic, which I am looking for.

Comment: Sure, "out of the box functionality" would be awesome. Seems like we're just not there, yet.

Comment: I thought we may be to tell you the truth with the Settings > Accounts options. I wonder when we will be there as this would be something that users coming from the two main players would expect. At the moment it can be done by forcing the sync but this should really be automatic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is resolved for me in the latest release. Now my calendar syncs automatically with the cloud and then back down to each de device. Check it out and see, as I am more than happy with it now.

Comment: Yes the latest OTA-12 release has resolved this issue for me. Now when I add/edit or delete an event in my calendar on one device, within a few minutes all my other Ubuntu devices are updated. The funny thing is that all my Ubuntu devices are updated but not my andriod phone, which I jave to manually sync.