# Is there a "account" package for Ubuntu Phone to connect to WebDav and CalDav server

Tags: ubuntu-touch, webdav, click-packages

I have been able to sync my calendar and contacts using the command line and a cron job, but I would like to have better integration into the system.

Is there a click package which already does this?

If not, is there some guide or example on how to get started to build this myself?

Thanks,
Joachim

Answer (score 1):

Someone may already create a script to process (I didn't test it yet)

Let's see [Romain Fluttaz](https://askubuntu.com/a/664834/400069) answer.

I don't know if it's "easy" to build a UI from that script.

To create an app, you could maybe start from [here](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/start/ubuntu-sdk/). Inside the Ubuntu-sdk, there are some examples too (I'm not familiar with, just tried to create a webapp one time and understand the sdk functions)

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I have written a small ubutu phoee app (using the Ubuntu SDK) but would not know who to link to the accounts.
For the syncing itself I currently have a working setup which uses a cron job, but I would like to get better integration.

Comment: What is the process of your app? I really like to test your app. May we should start a launchpad group for building and sharing an App for syncing contents...