# How do you move contact(s) between addressbooks in Ubuntu Touch?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, phone, contacts

I have created new contact in Personal addressbook. How do I move it to different addressbook? I would expect this option in contact edit, but it's not there :-)

(*Reason: personal addressbook is not synced to Google contacts.*)

Comment: Looks like currently no such option available. One has to add the contact manually once more. You may follow this bug report: http://pad.lv/1443900

Comment: Use [syncevolution](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SyncEvolution/) to sync contacts. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/360466/ and http://askubuntu.com/questions/616081/